# Regular Expression : Change syntax from perl to others with grep command

Tags: regex, linux, oracle, perl, grep

I want to find Oracle Error from the alert log file(on Linux) but some errors should be excluded.

Here is what I'm using which is perl syntax.

```
grep -P '.*^ORA-(?!.*(01013|16957))' alert_SID.log
```

This find the Oracle errors begining with 'ORA-'. But two errors that 'ORA-01013' OR 'ORA-16957' should be excluded

It works with `grep -P` option but other syntax doesn't work.

I'd like to change this syntax to work with extended-regexp(-E option) or others.

I have to apply this command to Monitoring Solution. The solution looks not support Perl syntax regular expression.

### Sample Input

```
Sat Mar 28 14:18:13 2015

ORA-01013: user requested cancel of current operation

Sat Mar 28 15:04:59 2015

ORA-01013: user requested cancel of current operation

Mon Mar 30 11:25:32 2015

ORA-01722: invalid number

ORA-1142 signalled during: ALTER DATABASE END BACKUP...

Thu Apr 02 01:59:38 2015

Wed Apr 08 15:49:52 2015

DW00 started with pid=1412, OS id=25801, wid=1, job SYS.SYS_EXPORT_TABLE_01

ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 3

ORA-28336: cannot encrypt SYS owned objects

Fri Apr 10 22:14:31 2015

ORA-16957: SQL Analyze time limit interrupt

Fri Apr 10 22:14:47 2015

ORA-16957: SQL Analyze time limit interrupt
```

### Desired Output

```
ORA-01722: invalid number

ORA-1142 signalled during: ALTER DATABASE END BACKUP...

ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 3

ORA-28336: cannot encrypt SYS owned objects
```

Comment: What's your actual question? You don't seem to ask one.

Comment: It is actually clear. OP needs a `grep` solution that would do the same thing as with the `-P` option, but without it.

Comment: Can you give us some examples of what should or shouldn't match? A replacement regex would need testing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anything remotely complicated you're better off using awk than grep since awk allows compound conditions, not just regexp matching:

```
$ awk '/ORA-/ && !/ORA-(01013|16957)/' file
ORA-01722: invalid number
ORA-1142 signalled during: ALTER DATABASE END BACKUP...
ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 3
ORA-28336: cannot encrypt SYS owned objects
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this command for your problem

```
grep -P 'ORA-\d+' alert_SID.log
```

or
you can modify your output using bellow command

```
grep -o -P  'ORA-\d+.*' alert_SID.log
```

So you can try any one depending on your choice.

Hope this will work for you.

Comment: can give some example for some part of your input file alert_SID.log and what you want to get from the file. then I believe , we can help you more properly.

Comment: you can put your input data information in your question and please mention what you want to get.

Comment: I'd like to change that syntax to extended regular expression which is -E option.

Comment: I do not have good idea about extended regular expression. Still In this  case of extended regular expression use  **grep -E 'ORA-16957|01013' alert_SID.log** .

Answer (score 1):

I would use the `-v` flag to filter out the unwanted lines, after first finding all of the `ORA-` lines.

The `-E` flag enables the `or` construct using a pipe `|`.

```
 $ grep 'ORA-' logfile | grep -Ev "ORA-01013|ORA-16957"

 ORA-01722: invalid number
 ORA-1142 signalled during: ALTER DATABASE END BACKUP...
 ORA-00604: error occurred at recursive SQL level 3
 ORA-28336: cannot encrypt SYS owned objects
```

**[man grep](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/grep.1.html)**

> ```
> -E, --extended-regexp
>      Interpret PATTERN as an extended regular expression
>
> -v, --invert-match
>      Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines.
> ```